# preg_match and preg_replace for youtube url

Tags: php

i have this code

```
preg_match_all('%(?:youtube\.com/(?:[^/]+/.+/|(?:v|e(?:mbed)?)/|.*[?&]v=)|youtu\.be/)([^"&?/ ]{11})%i', $asd, $match);
```

to find youtube key of urls like

```
<a href="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=">http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZiJRPREeQ1Q</a>
         <br />
         <a href="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GaEZgqxPHLs&feature=related">http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GaEZgqxPHLs&feature=related</a>
```

this work good to find the code ZiJRPREeQ1Q and GaEZgqxPHLs , now i want to replace all the html line with a new code

wanna to use

```
preg_replace
```

to find the whole youtube url

```
<a href="*">*</a>
```

to a new code  how can i do that ?

--------------adds--------------

after i get the code of youtube from url by preg_math_all
i used this code to extract the codes

```
foreach($match[1] as $youtube){
           // $youtube; // this handle the youtube code
           $match = "";  // what can i write here relative to $youtube ?
          $str .= preg_replace($match, 'new code',$content); // $content handle the whole thread that contain the youtube url <a href=*>*</a>                                  
         }
```

the only thing that i need that what's regular expression that i can use to replace youtube code

Comment: See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2129443/any-preg-match-to-check-if-a-url-is-a-youtube-vimeo-dailymotion-video-link) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1416425/preg-replace-preg-match-for-href-in-html-link)

Comment: If you "wanna to use" preg_replace, then you will have to learn how it works. It's entirely doable, but not suitable to beginners. (If you just wanted some readymade code, the search might turn up something.)

Comment: i update my post , read it please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$html = file_get_contents($url); //or curl function     
$re="<link itemprop=\"embedURL\" href=\"(.+)\">";
preg_match_all("/$re/siU", $html, $matches);
$youtube = $matches[1][0];
```

or

```
$html = file_get_contents($url); //or curl function     
$re="<link itemprop=\"url\" href=\"(.+)\">";
preg_match_all("/$re/siU", $html, $matches);
$youtube = $matches[1][0];
```

Comment: THAT'S will not replace !! i wanna replcae the html code of youtube from <a> to </a> into another code like $new