# How do I use PHP to find if a string contains a specific URL?

Tags: php, preg-match

I want to do a pattern match for certain domain names (using PHP). For example, if I am given a website URL, then I want to determine if that URL is from YouTube. The code below is what I tried, but it doesn't work (the if statement is always false). Any suggestions? Thanks ahead of time!

```
$website = trim( htmlentities( filter_var($_POST['website'], FILTER_SANITIZE_URL) ) );

if( preg_match("/youtube\.com/i", $website) )
{
    // do stuff
}
```

Comment: How is that not working?

Comment: take a look on the link http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php

Comment: Possible Duplicates: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2129443/any-preg-match-to-check-if-a-url-is-a-youtube-vimeo-dailymotion-video-link / http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4977233/regexp-to-find-youtube-url-strip-off-parameters-and-return-clean-video-url / http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1383073/php-validate-youtube-url / http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8027023/regex-php-auto-detect-youtube-image-and-regular-links

Comment: So, if `$website` was "http://www.google.com/?q=youtube.com", what would your expected behavior be? Could that ever happen? Perhaps something a little more robust like `parse_url()` and checking the "host" key could be more accurate.

Comment: I just updated the code to be more specific. The URL is coming from a form. Maybe it is the way I sanitize the URL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code looks fine to me...

```
<?php

$website = 'http://youtube.com/video?w=123455';

if( preg_match("#youtube\.com#i", $website, $matches) )
{
      print_r($matches);
}
```

**EDIT**

Still looks like it should work:

```
<?php

$_POST = array();
$_POST['website'] = 'http://youtube.com/video?w=123455';
$website = trim( htmlentities( filter_var($_POST['website'], FILTER_SANITIZE_URL)));

if( preg_match("#youtube\.com#i", $website, $matches) )
{
      print_r($matches);
}
```

OUTPUT

```
Array
(
    [0] => youtube.com
)
```

Answer (score 4):

You could use PHP's [parse_url](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) function. eg.

```
parse_url($POST['website'], PHP_URL_HOST);
```

This will give you the hostname. You can then use it for your checks

```
if(parse_url($POST['website'], PHP_URL_HOST) == 'youtube.com') // do something
```

Answer (score -1):

```
 if(strpos("youtube.com", $website) )
 {

   // do stuff
 }
```